# setCompundDrawables() not working in android M

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, compound-drawables

This is the code I am using to resize the drawable:

```
Drawable drawable = model_btn.getCompoundDrawables()[0];


        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (height * 0.065),
                (int) (height * 0.065));


        ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, 50, 50);
```

If I use

```
model_btn.setCompoundDrawables(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);
```

The drawable left is not showing.

If I use:

```
  model_btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(sd.getDrawable(), null, null, null);
```

It shows the drawable left but without resizing.

Your suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
model_btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.id, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: In this all the parameters need to be in, so I cant pass sd.getDrawable(), rather I have to pass the R.drawable.id of the drawable and then I cant resize the drawable in code.

Comment: This way I wiont be able to resize the drawable through code

Comment: go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198561/calculate-image-size-when-using-setcompounddrawables-for-edittext   or   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430893/resize-images-and-setcompounddrawableswithintrinsicbounds